# Socket.io with NGINX. Unable to do configurations for sockets to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io, configuration

I have my backend with socket.io and i want to configure socket.io with nginx. After nginx following configurations, I am able to make my routes other than sockets to work but my sockets are not working.

server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; #whatever port your app runs on
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

What are configuration that I need to do in (sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default) file to make sockets work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

to your location config ?

see https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio

Comment: yes but it is not working. Location configs are  location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;
        }
location /assets {
    alias /path/to/assets;
    access_log off;

Comment: which version of nginx are you running ?

Comment: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)